# node.js hangup on writing to console on win

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) completely hang up on writing to console at some stage in the app lifecycle. It happens only on windows. On linux all fine. But on win in any console e.g. *`cygwin`, `cmd`, `powershell`* it just hang up and do nothing on `console.log` or `process.stdout.write`.

It happens in [create-nuxt-app in Github](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app) in post install stage hook : [see more](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/blob/master/sao.js#L208).

Any write to stdout placed here will hang application at this stage on windows. If put `console.log` at top of this post hook it will hang on it, so the code in post hook doesn't matter.
 Its not isolated behavior on one windows PC, but rather happens on most ( or all) windows pc of different users.

**What could be a reason for this behavior and how to make it work ?**

Comment: Is this the actual code you're getting issues with? Can you check if [spawn in line 202](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/blob/3dbf667caeec2a72b619b5af06790c78e2b95267/sao.js#L202) is executed? If so, can you comment it out or add `false &&` in condition?

Comment: @MichałKapracki its actual code. Its executed. That line is not a problem. It stop as soon as first console.log happens. If i put console.log at the top of post function it will stop there ( before spawn or git init )

Comment: I see. I was looking for a hup or closing of stdout stream which could result in this. I guess you are using the same synchronous spawn in git init? If you leery me be inquisive: what would happen if you remove both spawns? Maybe the effect goes after first write to stdout from the main process? What if you don't inherit stdio?

Comment: run fiddler and see if it does a call to a server and if its a upload or download.

Comment: @DeerSpotter what call to server it could do if it hang up on console.log ?

Comment: @Aldarund could you describe in more details how you execute this project. I made on Windows `npx create-nuxt-app sample-app`, and everything works, I clone the repo and run `npm i`, and everything works without a hangup

Comment: @Łukasz Szewczak not sure about npx, but it happens with yarn for sure or with node itself. I don't have a PC at moment. So to reproduce you can just yarn create nuxt-app or node  pathtorepodir/cli.js . Although I think it should be also happen on npx, just don't remember. Another thing that it might happen not on all windows. But users complains about this and I was able to reproduce it locally as well as other developer on vm.

Comment: and the post hook runs fine in windows without any of the console.logs?

Comment: @Emil yes, that's correct as I remember. Although the console.log last lines, nothing really happen after them.

Comment: What's the indication that it's hung up, and what's the signal that the command failed/succeeded with/without the console logs? Asking since you said nothing really happens after the console logs. (and the difference between what happens when the console logs are at the top vs the bottom)

Comment: @Emil nothing happens. Terminal is open. It didn't finish.process is running. No code is executed after first console. So app dont exit at all, there no exit code because of it :) if at top no git repo created (gitinit function call)

Comment: Any particular version of windows ? Might it be something like this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321945/nodejs-console-log-hangs-and-prints-everything-in-one-line ?

Comment: @Daniel M. Win 10 stable & latest slow ring for sure. It's not much related to cmd, because it's reproduced in cygwin, powershell too

Comment: Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a lot of users on other sites are confirming that the culprit is this:

I see `wslbscrwh64.dll` in the dump, which is not usual. It would seem it is this thing: `http://www.dieboldnixdorf.com.br/warsaw`

> Wow, thanks, it really was Warsaw! I never asked it to install and I
>   always see if a software installs others to disable it (installing
>   others that I don't want), but some software must have installed
>   Warsaw without my consent (I don't use this machine for accessing bank
>   accounts, so I don't know what installed Warsaw).
>
> When I ran node -v, it showed v8.9.4 and than hanged. When I ran npm
>   -v (or any npm command) it simply hanged (without doing nothing). Sometimes with npm, if I ended the node process it worked for the
>   hanging process (but hanged the next time the command was executed).
>
> When I installed npm and node again the problem was solved, then in
>   the next day it returned.
>
> **Uninstalling Warsaw solved it imediatelly**

**Another user:**

> I confirm the culprit is warsaw. I just uninstalled it (while node was
>   hanging) and even without restart, node stop to hang.

credit: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18436